# Creating an array of n numbers excluding k given numbers efficiently

Tags: c, arrays

How can I create an array of numbers starting from 1 and ending to n while not including k given numbers in the array ? For example n=10 k=2 and two numbers for the value of k are 3 and 6 then my array is 1,2,4,5,7,8,9,10.

I have to do this for large numbers like when

1 < n < 10^9

then

0 < k < min(10^5,n)

For small numbers I tried indexing and then storing it in a different array which took lot of space and time.How can I do it efficiently?

```
            scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&k);
            f=0;
            long long int a[100010]={0};
            long long int b[100010]={0};
            for(i=0;i<k;i++)
            {
            scanf("%lld",&temp);
            a[temp]=-1;
            }
            for(i=0;i<n+1;i++)
            {
                if(a[i]!=-1)
                {
                b[f++]=i;
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should post the code you've tried and where you're experiencing inefficiency

Comment: Surely it would be easier to create an array of size `k` to hold your k values instead of creating an array of size `n` and subtracting from it all your k values?  In your example, you could create an array of size 2 and store in it the numbers 3 and 6.

Comment: Can you assume 4G ram available to the process?

Comment: can we assume the K exclusions will be presented in order?

Comment: No can't assume 4G ram and k exclusions in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `n` as the end of the range, `k` as the number of skipped numbers, `narr` as the array holding the results, and `karr` as the array holding the numbers to skip:  `karr` need only be `k` elements long.  If `karr` is sorted, you only need to compare each new number against one element from `karr`, moving to the next `karr` when they match and adding the new number to `narr` when they don't.  The following example shows this (but has no error checks):

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for malloc and qsort
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf

// compare function for qsort
static int llcompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    if (*(long long *)a > *(long long *)b) return 1;
    if (*(long long *)b < *(long long *)b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    long long n = 0, k = 0;
    scanf("%lld%lld",&n,&k); // get n and k, as in your code

    // allocate arrays: k elements for karr, and (n - k) for results in narr
    long long *karr = malloc(sizeof(long long) * k);
    long long *narr = malloc(sizeof(long long) * (n - k));

    // read numbers to skip into karr
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        scanf("%lld", &karr[i]);
    }
    // sort karr ascending
    qsort(karr,k,sizeof(long long),llcompare);

    // using pointers to move through narr and karr
    long long *pn = narr; // element of narr to set
    long long *pk = karr; // element of karr to compare against

    // pkend marks the end of karr, to check when we've passed the last omitted
    // number
    long long *pkend = karr + k;

    // loop over the needed range
    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (pk != pkend && i == *pk) {
            // if i is the next number to omit, move pk to the next omitted
            // number (without adding i to results)
            pk++;
        } else {
            // otherwise, add i to results then move pn to the next element
            *(pn++) = i;
        }
    }

    // print results from narr
    for (long long i = 0; i < (n - k); i++)
        printf("%lld ", narr[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // free karr and narr when done
    free(karr);
    free(narr);

  return 0;
}
```

There's no need for a huge lookup table, and since the numbers being added to the results only increase, the next number to skip will always be the lowest number in `karr` that hasn't already been reached... so it's only necessary to check one element from `karr` for each new number.

The code above also assumes that there are no numbers in `karr` that won't be checked in the loop, that is that there are no numbers in `karr` that are outside the range of 1..n.  And because of the lack of error checking/handling, it may behave badly if you give it invalid input or `malloc()` fails for some reason.